# How to make stop loss in pine script strategy?

Tags: pine-script

When take profit worked i need to close 50% of my qty but when stop loss worked i need to close all my position. My code:

```
strategy.exit("long profit", "long", limit = take, qty_percent=50)
strategy.exit("long stop", "long", stop = stop)
```

[And i am getting result like there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFlP5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have two exit orders but only one of them have the stop loss value set. Instead, all of them should have the `stop` argument.

```
strategy.exit("long profit", "long", limit = take, stop=stop, qty_percent=50)
strategy.exit("long stop", "long", stop = stop)
```